# Argument "DUTOIT" for option "connection" is not valid. Error when trying to run SSIS Package using command line in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: ssis

This is the code I use when trying to run it in SQL Management Studio.

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /FILE "C:\Users\luka.milutinovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SSISDemo\SSISDemo\SSISDemo\Package1.dtsx" /CONNECTION "DUTOIT-PC\SQLSERVER2008R2.SSIS.sa";"\"Data Source=DUTOIT-PC\SQLSERVER2008R2;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=SSIS;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-Package1-{6B84DB73-E7A7-4227-9072-2AEB870E60A9}DUTOIT-PC\SQLSERVER2008R2.SSIS.sa;\"" /CONNECTION LogFile;"C:\Users\luka.milutinovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SSISDemo\LogFile" /CONNECTION Middle;"C:\Users\luka.milutinovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SSISDemo\Person_Middle_12.csv" /CONNECTION Old;"C:\Users\luka.milutinovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SSISDemo\Person_Old_12.csv" /CONNECTION Young;"C:\Users\luka.milutinovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SSISDemo\Person_Young_12.csv"  /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW  /LOGGER "{0A039101-ACC1-4E06-943F-279948323883}";LogFile '

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a variable through DTEXEC with xp\_cmdshell (SQL Server 2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982780/passing-a-variable-through-dtexec-with-xp-cmdshell-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Your code is quite unreadable, could you please improve its formatting?

Answer (score 0):

xp_cmdshell only allows for [one set of double quoted parameters to be passed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266224).

### References

- [SSIS package hangs while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921093/ssis-package-hangs-while-running/15933126#15933126)
- [Passing a variable through DTEXEC with xp_cmdshell (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982780/passing-a-variable-through-dtexec-with-xp-cmdshell-sql-server-2008/10984198#10984198)